# "У подножЬя" или "у подножИя"?

Tags: орфография

Как правильно: "у подножЬя" или "у подножИя"?

Answer (score 2):

И в орфографическом, и в орфоэпическом словарях есть только слово "подножие". Следовательно, **у подножия**. Допускаю, что где-то в поэтическом тексте может встретиться и *у подножья*, но это будет авторский вариант, обусловленный, например, рамками стихотворного размера. Нормой же является, повторюсь, **у подножия**.

Answer (score -1):

Подножья Сущёв Никита